# How to load local go file by using gore

Tags: go, read-eval-print-loop

I installed `gore` to use REPL.

And I want to check behavior of a `ParseFullTimeSpec` function in this file.

https://github.com/dshearer/jobber/blob/master/jobfile/time_spec.go#L79

I tried by `:import github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile/time_spec.go`, but it returned a error `error: import: can't find import:`

I also tried relative path after `git clone`, but I couldn't import it anyway.

What is a right way to load the go file from `gore`?

#### Installing the package to workplace

To install the package to my workplace I did like this:

```
mkdir $GOPATH/src/github.com/dshearer
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/dshearer
git clone git@github.com:dshearer/jobber.git
go install github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile
```

It returns a error:

```
# github.com/dshearer/jobber/common
src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo.go:15: undefined: sudo_cmd
```

And I couldn't install `common` package with a error `undefined: sudo_cmd`.

```
go install github.com/dshearer/jobber/common
# github.com/dshearer/jobber/common
src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo.go:15: undefined: sudo_cmd
```

Comment: About `src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo.go:15: undefined: sudo_cmd` What is your current system os ? see file suffixes at https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool, maybe this explains that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the package itself, which [that file is a part of](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Overview). You can't import files separately in go.

```
:import github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile
```

Comment: I got same error `import: can't find import:` when I input `:import github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile` in `gore`. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to add the package to my go workspace, but it failed. I wrote the process of it in my question. Sorry, this must be a basic knowledge of `go`, but I really couldn't find out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

So there two problems:

1) You can import packages, but not specific files (package might contain multiple files)

2) The source code and error about sudo_cmd - sudo_cmd is available only on Linux and FreeBSD platforms. See:

```
nkts@zulu ~ $ ls -l go/src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo_cmd_*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nkts nkts 214 Nov 22 22:28 go/src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo_cmd_freebsd.go
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nkts nkts 229 Nov 22 22:28 go/src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo_cmd_linux.go
```

So it should not work on Windows or MacOSX.

But clearly works on Linux (with auto complete):

```
nkts@zulu ~ $ go get -u github.com/motemen/gore
nkts@zulu ~ $ go get -v github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile
github.com/dshearer/jobber (download)
github.com/dshearer/jobber/Godeps/_workspace/src/gopkg.in/yaml.v2
github.com/dshearer/jobber/common
github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile
nkts@zulu ~ $ gore
gore version 0.2.6  :help for help
gore> :import github.com/dshearer/jobber/jobfile
gore> jobfile.ErrorHandlerStopNam^C
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last output seems to show you're doing it right, but the source code you're using is not in proper state:

```
go install github.com/dshearer/jobber/common
# github.com/dshearer/jobber/common
src/github.com/dshearer/jobber/common/sudo.go:15: undefined: sudo_cmd
```

Looking at the sources for jobber, it appears it has a [Makefile](https://github.com/dshearer/jobber/blob/master/Makefile), which is supposed to add the missing function for your architecture.

This project actually has specific install instructions, you can [find them here](http://dshearer.github.io/jobber/doc/v1.1/).

```
cd /path/to/your/workspace
go get github.com/dshearer/jobber
cd src/github.com/dshearer/jobber
git checkout v1.1
make GO_WKSPC=/path/to/your/workspace
```

PS: note that the canonical way to install dependency in your `$GOPATH` is to use `go get`:

```
go get host.com/namespace/package
```

This is not enough here, though, as package author decided to have an adhoc build mechanism.